# Python JSON Functionality with raw strings

Tags: python, json

i get the following json variable (string):

```
var = somefunct()
print(var)

'{"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","user_id_str":"44196397"}}}'
```

When I try to loads it

```
json.loads(var)
```

I get : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:`

but, when I do something like that **manually**:

```
new_var = r"""{"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","user_id_str":"44196397"}}}"""
json.loads(new_var)
{'data': {'threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2': {'source': '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>', 'user_id_str': '44196397'}}}
```

It works.
Simply put, it looks like this

```
a = """{"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","user_id_str":"44196397"}}}"""
b = r"""{"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","user_id_str":"44196397"}}}"""
json.loads(a) - ERROR
json.loads(b) - WORKS
```

How I can solve it, when I have some variable?

How I can make content in my "var" variable to r"content" for json.loads method?

UPD: After a lot of wasted time, I found out that it is impossible to get the string data that I indicated with my example. Thanks for answers. The issue was resolved.

Comment: I think `print(var)` shows that your value in `var` is wrapped in an extra level of string quotes... it wouldn't output between `'...'` otherwise

Comment: @Anentropic Of course, I understand this very well. The question is how to convert a similar string to a dictionary

Comment: Also, it works only on variable `b` because you are not taking care of the backslash key. If you write """\""", the python interpreter will not understand what you mean. But you write """\\""", it will understand this is a string. When writing r"""\""", python understand you actually meant for a double slash.

Comment: So you should put this on variable `a`: """{"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"source":"<a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">Twitter for iPhone</a>","user_id_str":"44196397"}}}"""

Comment: Now, again, this loads a string. Not a dictionary.

Comment: Ah no, my bad, it does return a dictionary. I fogot to print `type(json.load(a))`. I was printing `type(a)` without assigning `a` the value of `json.load(a)`. But you get the idea. The backslash is your problem.

Comment: There seems to be a slight inconsistency between your first and last examples: in `var` double quotes around `href` and `rel` are correctly escaped while they are not in `a`. `a` is  malformed to be loaded as json.

Comment: Are you the one generating the value of `var` returned from `somefunct`?  Your best bet would be to get valid JSON data in the first place instead of being stuck with something incorrectly escaped and wrapped in extra quotes

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, you were absolutely right. After a lot of wasted time, I found out that it is impossible to get the string data that I indicated with my example. Thanks for answers. The issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I  had this same issue, I tried many ways, such as `var = var.encode('unicode_escape')`, or using `.encode('utf-8')`, but the only solution I could find is using:

```
var = rf"{var}"
var_dict = json.loads(var)
# previous 2 lines combined in one:  var_dict = json.loads(rf"{var}")
```

Answer (score -2):

if you use `json.loads(json.dumps(var))` then it will work.
The reason is you have " in the value of data.threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2.source that caused the error

Comment: no it won't work. As you know, "loads" returns a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: @fer0m thats why I use json.dumps inside json.loads. I test it and it works with the same var you use. if you explain what we need we may help you

Comment: `json.dumps()` takes a dictionary, not a string, and `var` is a string. See here for example usage of `json.dumps()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @jjramsey json.dumps convert Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str it can take str and convert it to formatted str without issue, try it yourself. if the goal is to convert the str to dict but the str is not well formated then you can use json.dumps to convert it to formatted str then json.loads to convert it to dict

Comment: Point taken that `json.dumps()` takes more than dictionaries. That said, it converts Python objects to their corresponding string analogs in JSON, so `json.dumps([])` returns the string `"[]"`, and `json.dumps('foo""')` returns the string `"foo\"\""`. If you feed `json.dumps()` a string that happens to be a malformed JSON expression, it will treat the string as any other string, escaping special characters like `"`, but not converting it to a valid JSON representation. That your method seems to work is largely luck and an "abuse" of `json.dumps()` intended functionality.